# django display context data in template without calling view through url

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I have written a view:

```
class ShowNotifications(TemplateView):

context = {}
model = Notification
template_name = "notifications.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ShowNotifications,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['unseen_notifications'] =  Notification.objects.filter(body__user=self.request.user).filter(viewed=False)
    context['seen_notifications'] = Notification.objects.filter(body__user=self.request.user).filter(viewed=True)
    return context
```

And I have displayed its context in my template. I have created a notification pop up where user can see the notification like in facebook where after login they can see their notifications.

I have made "notifications.html" and included it in notification nav.  When I click it dont show anything. But when I call the view through url like `url(r'^notifications/', ShowNotifications.as_view(), name='notifin') ,` it shows the notification but I want it to be displayed in pop up.

How can I make this possible....??
Need help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add certain variables to the context of every view, rather than just this one.

One way to do it is using a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS):

```
# myapp/context_processors.py

def notifications(request):
    "Context processor for adding notifications to the context."
    return {
        'unseen_notifications': Notification.objects.filter(
            body__user=request.user).filter(viewed=False),
        'seen_notifications': Notification.objects.filter(
            body__user=request.user).filter(viewed=True),
    }
```

You'd also need to add the context processor to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS:

```
# settings.py

...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myapp.context_processors.notifications',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to include template view via "include" template tag. Include loads template in current context https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include.

It seems to me that you should use custom template tag for your purpose.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: what about list view?? What if I use list view instead of template view and use it.. U mentioned its impossible for template view. What about other views ??

Comment: "include" template tag works on current context, so it's no matter which type of view you are using, really you just render template - get_context_data method doesn't called.